# Custom Payload in dialogflow is not responding

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es

I have made s simple Custom payload for a text response in my Dialog flow response

```
{
  "messages": [
    {
      "speech": "Text response",
      "type": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

But its giving me the response `Not available`

Here is my Raw Api response

```
{
  "id": "d5143e9a-e578-474f-bca4-fe993dd62649",
  "timestamp": "2018-10-02T08:30:54.035Z",
  "lang": "en",
  "result": {
    "source": "agent",
    "resolvedQuery": "what do you know about Data science",
    "action": "",
    "actionIncomplete": false,
    "parameters": {},
    "contexts": [],
    "metadata": {
      "intentId": "a1c71c95-3126-4076-81f7-ddf7a4da1bad",
      "webhookUsed": "false",
      "webhookForSlotFillingUsed": "false",
      "isFallbackIntent": "false",
      "intentName": "data1"
    },
    "fulfillment": {
      "speech": "",
      "messages": [
        {
          "type": 4,
          "payload": {
            "messages": [
              {
                "speech": "Text response",
                "type": 0
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "score": 1
  },
  "status": {
    "code": 200,
    "errorType": "success"
  },
  "sessionId": "df6b3e49-d49b-4311-cb9f-2946febfcc8b"
}
```

Here is Screenshot
[image]
I am unable to understand this problem..Thanks in advance........................................................................................

Comment: What Dialogflow integration are you using?  Where are you getting the "Not available" error? Are you using fulfillment?  Were is the response defined (in the console on in fulfillment)?  Have you made sure the response is defined for you target platform?

Comment: Right now  I am testing this with in dialog flow.(i want to implement that with Skype)(screenshot added in question)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `square brackets` after `fulfillment`. Try using brackets as marked in bold. Also not sure if fulfillment alone will work write fulfillmentMessages

```
"fulfillment": [{
      "speech": "",
      "messages": [
        {
          "type": 4,
          "payload": {
            "messages": [
              {
                "speech": "Text response",
                "type": 0
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "score": 1
  },
  "status": {
    "code": 200,
    "errorType": "success"
  },
  "sessionId": "df6b3e49-d49b-4311-cb9f-2946febfcc8b"
}]
```